# Is it possible to change the output to be an actual string of characters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I created this function to output all account IDs for my aws accounts cross regions but the output I am getting is quite unintelligible

trying de-referencing like in c++

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"

    //"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
   // "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    //"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/stscreds"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/organizations"
)

func main()  {
    listAccounts()
}

func listAccounts() {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    svc := organizations.New(sess)
    input := &organizations.ListAccountsInput{}


    result, err := svc.ListAccounts(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case organizations.ErrCodeAccessDeniedException:
                fmt.Println(organizations.ErrCodeAccessDeniedException, aerr.Error())
            case organizations.ErrCodeAWSOrganizationsNotInUseException:
                fmt.Println(organizations.ErrCodeAWSOrganizationsNotInUseException, aerr.Error())
            case organizations.ErrCodeInvalidInputException:
                fmt.Println(organizations.ErrCodeInvalidInputException, aerr.Error())
            case organizations.ErrCodeServiceException:
                fmt.Println(organizations.ErrCodeServiceException, aerr.Error())
            case organizations.ErrCodeTooManyRequestsException:
                fmt.Println(organizations.ErrCodeTooManyRequestsException, aerr.Error())
            default:
                fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    return
}
    // fmt.Println(result.Accounts)
    var accountList []*string

    for _, accountId := range result.Accounts {
        accountList = append(accountList, accountId.Id)
    }
    fmt.Println(accountList)

}
```

go run id.go
[0xc0002387e0 0xc000238840 0xc0002388a0 0xc000238900 0xc000238960 0xc0002389c0 0xc000238a20 0xc000238a80 0xc000238ae0 0xc000238b40 0xc000238ba0 0xc000238c00 0xc000238c60 0xc000238cc0 0xc000238d20 0xc000238d80 0xc000238de0 0xc000238e40 0xc000238ea0 0xc000238f00]

Comment: You say you're `trying de-referencing like in c++`, but you're not dereferencing anything. Do you need to work with a `[]string` or a `[]*string`?

Comment: `[]*string` to let it know what to assign the var to

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that means. `fmt` is obviously not going to print `[]*string` in the way to want, so if you want to print it you need to iterate over the pointers. Is the end goal just to print, or are you going to marshal this into something else?

Comment: using it for a lambda caller

Comment: What does that mean? Do you need to format it as a string? Do you need to format it as json? If that's the case, why do you have a `[]*string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking `*string`s when you really only need `string`s. It's a simple change to derefernce the pointers you get back from AWS SDK (it uses pointers for everything for nullability):

```
var accountList []string

for _, accountId := range result.Accounts {
    accountList = append(accountList, *accountId.Id)
}
fmt.Println(accountList)
```